# Hide/Show a checkbox based on json value

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular-material

I have 4 check boxes and I want to hide/show them based on the value that I am getting in my JSON. I'll get only one name of checkbox in my JSON and only that particular checkbox will be shown to user and it'll be marked as checked. How can I do that? Here is my material checkbox code

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" class="py-8" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly">
  <mat-checkbox>Fragile</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox>Flyer</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox>Time Stipulated</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox>Gift Wrapped</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Here is my json

[image]

Since I am getting name as flyer so only flyer checkbox will be shown to user as checked while all other will not be shown to user.

Comment: I am using reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

Not Cleared with your question. You are using Mat-checkbox without using of JSON file
If your Json will be

```
SampleJson= [
{
    Name: "Fragile",
    isActive: true
},
{
    Name: "Flyer",
    isActive: true
},
{
    name: "Time Stipulated",
    isActive: true
},
{
    name: "Gift Wrapped",
    isActive: false
},
```

]

then modify your html to

```html
<div fxLayout="row wrap" class="py-8" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="SampleJson[0].isActive">Fragile</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="SampleJson[1].isActive">Flyer</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="SampleJson[3].isActive">Time Stipulated</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="SampleJson[0].isActive">Gift Wrapped</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Hope it works for you. Happy coding